# ion-select default value not working with ngfor in ion-select-option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

This is my ionic code which I wrote for `ion-select`

```
<ion-item lines="none" type="input">
  <ion-label position="stacked" color="primary">Skill level</ion-label>
  <ion-select
    [formControl]="selectedSkill"
    color="white"
    class="ion-padding-start" value="{{ student.level }}">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let level of levels" value="{{ level }}" color="primary">
      {{ level }}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

The default value is working fine when I click the select element once. But it is not prefilled once I open the page.

Comment: What do you mean this "But it is not prefilled once I open the page."?

Comment: Default value is shown only after clicking the dropdown once... It is not shown by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I haven't initiated the `levels` array. After I have added an empty array it is working fine.